# UIPickerView 3 colunas

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Eu quero fazer um uipickerview com três colunas, porém só a primeira aparece carregada as outras vazias, não encontro o erro caso alguém saiba resolver agradeço.
Segue abaixo o código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
static string[] nomesPeso = new string[]
        {
            "Back Squat",
            "Front Squat",
            "OHS - Overhead Squat"
        };

static string[] nomesUnidades = new string[]
        {
            "Reps",
            "Kgs",
            "Lbs",
            "Metros"
        };

static string[] nomesRepeticoes = new string[]
        {
            "1 RM",
            "2 RM",
            "3 RM"
        };

public override nint GetComponentCount(UIPickerView v)
        {
            return 3;
        }

        public override nint GetRowsInComponent(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
        {
            switch (component)
            {
                case 0:
                    return nomesPeso.Length;
                case 1:
                    return nomesRepeticoes.Length; 
                case 2:
                    return nomesUnidades.Length;
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public override string GetTitle(UIPickerView picker, nint row, nint component)
        {
            switch (component)
            {
                case 0:
                    return nomesPeso[row];
                case 1:
                    return nomesRepeticoes[row]; 
                case 2:
                    return nomesUnidades[row];
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Não estão vazias, é a largura da primeira coluna que está grande demais.
Você pode usar o método `pickerView:widthForComponent:` para ajustar a largura.
Documentação: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html